# Pygame Event Queue Max

Tags: python, events, queue, pygame

I'm taking some data over the network and inputing it into Pygame as Events.

If the network is congested or the connection drops briefly, a lot of data comes at once when it becomes decongested. When that happens, the event queue fills up fast to the point it gives me this error:

```
error: Event queue full
```

Searching different sites has not yielded me any answers. What is the maximum number of events in queue in Pygame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pygame is built upon SDL, and everything I've been able to find says the SDL event queue has a 127 element limit.  What library are you using to push networking on to the queue?  It seems like it would take an awful lot of network traffic to flood the event queue if you are flushing it every game loop, even if it gets backed up.  Also, what events specifically are you queuing here?  Maybe you should be buffering your network traffic each game loop and throwing out irrelevant information so you don't generate as many events.

Comment: Thanks, I was using pygame.event.wait() instead of taking it all at once with pygame.event.get().